# Is it possible to rewrite this nonlinear equation as a linear equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is not clear to me why part (c) is possible to write it in a linear form. I've solved (a) and (b) but the solution provided by Chegg states that it is possible to write part (c) in a linear form.

part (a) -> $\frac{dx}{dt} - \ln(2) x = 0$ and part (b) is $\frac{(x+1)((x-1)}{x-1} = x+1$.

[image]

Chegg solution

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Case c. is just equation
$$
x'=x^2+1,
$$
which is NOT linear. In fact is a Riccati type equation, and if you make the transformation
$$
x'=i+\frac{1}{y},
$$
where $i^2=-1$, you obtain for $y$ the linear equation
$$
y'=-2iy-1.
$$

Comment: The problem is presented in the book before any sort of transformation technique, so I'm guessing the solution in Chegg website is wrong, right? Also, their justification is equivocal if not amiss.

Comment: which book @CroCo

Answer (score 1):

$$x'=x^2+1,$$
Becomes linear if you substitute $x=-\dfrac {u'}{u}$
$$u''+u=0$$
It's now linear but of order two.